# Machine learning methods for filtering noisy data

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras, caret

I have my data (hear beat) cleaned up with the appropriate filter, however, they are still noisy and need to extract a clean pattern. Which is the best algorithm for this purpose?

I have also clean data where the pattern is clear and could be used as a reference to extract the pattern.

Many thanks

Comment: Check out [denoising autoencoders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder#Denoising_autoencoder_(DAE)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! My data are continuous variable, do you think these autoencoders could work? I read that can be used for stimuli like photos and similar

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "continuous". Do you mean that your signals have values that range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$? If so, then variational autoencoders can also work with these kinds of signals. However, to get them to work, you need to scale your signals so that they span a closed interval, such as $[0,1]$. You should also use the binary [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) loss function if you scale the signals to $[0,1]$.